# How to avoid multiple token refresh requests when making simultaneous API requests with an expired token

Tags: javascript, axios, jwt, refresh-token

API request using JWT is implemented in flask and Vue.js.
The JWT is stored in a cookie, and the server validates the JWT for each request.

If the token has expired, a 401 error will be returned.
f you receive a 401 error, refresh the token as in the code below,
The original API request is made again.
The following code is common to all requests.

```
http.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response;
}, error => {
    if (error.config && error.response && error.response.status === 401 && !error.config._retry) {
        error.config._retry = true;
        http
            .post(
                "/token/refresh",
                {},
                {
                    withCredentials: true,
                    headers: {
                        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": Vue.$cookies.get("csrf_refresh_token")
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status == 200) {
                    const config = error.config;
                    config.headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = Vue.$cookies.get("csrf_access_token");
                    return Axios.request(error.config);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {

            });
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

When making multiple API requests at the same time with the token expired
Uselessly refreshing the token.
For example, requests A, B, and C are executed almost simultaneously.
Since 401 is returned with each request,
Each interceptor will refresh the token.

There is no real harm, but I don't think it's a good way.
There is a good way to solve this.

My idea is to first make an API request to validate the token expiration,
This method is to make requests A, B, and C after verification and refresh are completed.
Because cookies are HttpOnly, the expiration date cannot be verified on the client side (JavaScript).

Sorry in poor english...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What you'll need to do is maintain some state outside the interceptor. Something that says

> Hold up, I'm in the middle of getting a new token.

This is best done by keeping a reference to a `Promise`. That way, the first 401 interceptor can create the promise, then all other requests can wait for it.

```js
let refreshTokenPromise // this holds any in-progress token refresh requests

// I just moved this logic into its own function
const getRefreshToken = () => http.post('/token/refresh', {}, {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': Vue.$cookies.get('csrf_refresh_token') }
}).then(() => Vue.$cookies.get('csrf_access_token'))

http.interceptors.response.use(r => r, error => {
  if (error.config && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
    if (!refreshTokenPromise) { // check for an existing in-progress request
      // if nothing is in-progress, start a new refresh token request
      refreshTokenPromise = getRefreshToken().then(token => {
        refreshTokenPromise = null // clear state
        return token // resolve with the new token
      })
    }

    return refreshTokenPromise.then(token => {
      error.config.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token
      return http.request(error.config)
    })
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

Comment: I used on a React project (with minor modifications) and worked fine too. Thanks!

Comment: @FernandoBarbosa Can you share your code to me ?!

Comment: Modified this for Vue3 and worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: should the refresh token api call be awaited? I'm thinking no because we're holding onto the promise?

Comment: @OverMars that promise is returned by the interceptor so it does actually wait